# Trying to get property of non-object when Json data seed on laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

i want to seed json data using seeder in laravel. when i migrate and seed using `php artisan migrate --seed` command following message will appear in command line

```
In PaymentTableSeeder.php line 19:

  Trying to get property 'identity' of non-object
```

**payment-gateway.json**

```
 [  
   {  
      "identity":"Stripe",
      "config":{  
         "Publishable key":"",
         "Secret key":""
      },
      "status":0
   }
]
```

**PaymentTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PaymentTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $json = File::get('database/data/payment-gateway.json');
        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        foreach($data as $obj){
            DB::table('payment_settings')->insert([
                'identity' => $obj->identity,
                'config' => $obj->config,
                'status' => $obj->status
            ]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out `$obj` to see what is being evaluated?

Answer (score 5):

```
 $data = json_decode($json, true);
```

The second parameter means that you get the result as assoc array. Either remove the parameter or access the data via

```
$obj['identity']
```

See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: In Connection.php line 664:
                                                                                                                          
  Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `payment_settings` (`identity`, `config`, `status`) values (Stripe, , 0))  
                                                                                                                          

In MySqlConnection.php line 80:
                              
  Array to string conversion

Comment: That error pops up because the "config" key is an array with two element "Publishable key" and "Secret key".

Imho this data should go to a different config_table and the id could be saved as a foreign key into your payment_settings config field.

Comment: i want to store on json data  {"Publishable key":"", "Secret key":""} in config field

Comment: 'config' => json_encode($obj['config'])  is what you are probably want to do then